# Accessing ServiceStack request outside of SS context

Tags: c#, servicestack, nlog

I'm trying to assign a global request/tracing id to all my incoming requests in a ServiceStack api. I have solved this by adding the following Pre request filter:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((request, response) =>
{
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
    request.Items["RequestId"] = requestId;
});
```

Which all works perfectly fine - I can see the request id in my custom ServiceStack service runner and everything.

The problem arise when I wish to write this request id to my logs. I'm using Nlog, and have created the following custom layout renderer:

```
public class RequestIdLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        if (ServiceStackHost.Instance == null) return;
        var request = ServiceStackHost.Instance.TryGetCurrentRequest();
        if (request == null) return;

        object requestId;
        if (!request.Items.TryGetValue("RequestId", out requestId)) return;

        builder.Append(requestId);
    }
}
```

The problem is: when the `request` is returned, the `Items` collection is containing only the default ServiceStack element `AspSessionIDManagerInitializeRequestCalled`.

My question is: Is this the intended behaviour, and if yes, then how do I go about retrieving the `Items` collection "outside" of the ServiceStack scope?
Is there a better way to share this request id so NLog can pick it up? 
I have already tried the `MappedDiagnosticsContext` in Nlog, but for strange reasons, some of the log entries are missing the RequestId, so this is an attempt to avoid using the context.

The ServiceStack version is 4.0.52 and .net version 4.6 on Windows 10 Update 1. Nlog version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServiceStack ASP.NET `IRequest` retains a local copy of Dictionary Items that's originally sourced but decoupled from the underlying ASP.NET Request. If you want to share data outside of the Context of a ServiceStack Request but within the same ASP.NET Request than you can use the `HttpContext.Current` singleton, e.g:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((request, response) =>
{
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
    HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestId"] = requestId;

    //Alternative API:
    //var aspReq = (HttpRequestBase)request.OriginalRequest;
    //aspReq.Items["RequestId"] = requestId;
});
```